# How to check a single time if UserDefaults is empty

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, nsuserdefaults

My app counts the days between a date and NSDate(). When I released it, a user could only save one date, a title and a background image.

Now I have a UICollectionView with the option to save more than one date, and it will create a cell by appending a date, title and image string to their respective arrays.

The app has been completely changed, so I'm struggling with how to check whether a user has saved a date, and if they have, add that info to the arrays to create a cell.

But, I want this to only been checked once - the first time the app is opened from update or fresh install.

Here is my thinking about it, it doesn't work by the way.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if userDefault.objectForKey("day") == nil {
    } else {
        // Add the first date created from previous version
        let day = userDefault.objectForKey("day") as? String
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(day!)!
        let date1 = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        addDateToArray(date1)

        // Add the since text
        let text = userDefault.objectForKey("sinceText") as? String
        addSinceLabelToArray(text!)

         //Add the image background
        let image = userDefault.objectForKey("khoury") as! String
        addThemeToImagesArray(image)
    }
```

What happens with the code above is it returns nil. I am expecting it to create the first cell, so that the user can see the date they have saved.

Comment: Take the opportunity to adopt Core Data for storage rather than NSUserDefaults.  When the user first launches the new version, check for a NSUserDefaults value, migrate it to your Core Data and then delete the NSUserDefaults value.

Comment: "it doesn't work" tells us all very little about your problem. What did you expect to happen, what did you see instead, what do you think that means is happening?

Comment: @Jonah Made an edit

Comment: `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is the wrong place to be retrieving data.  This function is called to display data; if your array is empty then there is no data to be displayed and it won't be called.  You should load data in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @Khoury sorry it's still not clear to me what your problem is. Which statement returns nil? We can't see where you define `userDefault`, what any of the `add*Array` methods do or what this `cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns so it's very hard to piece together anything about what you code is doing much less what you want it to do.

Comment: @Paulw11 Say I put this is 'viewDidLoad', I don't want this to be called every time the view loads, just once. My more specific question would be how to check if user defaults is empty a single time

Comment: I don't understand that logic;  If defaults is nil, then add the first item and then save userdefaults.  From that point on it won't be nil.  You don't "check once", you simply set something so next time you check it isn't empty. You need to load the data every time, but as I said, don't use NSUserDefaults for this.  Use Core Data

Comment: @Paulw11 My code isn't suitable because as soon as I delete a cell, NSUserDefaults becomes empty and will create a new cell when app relaunches. You're right about that. That's why I need to call it once only because in the previous version, I want to take that single date saved and use it. I only want to check this on opening the update, hence the single time use.

Comment: Then you can set another boolean in NSUserDefaults that indicates whether you have done the check or not.

Comment: How do I do that (sounds like the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another boolean value in `NSUserDefaults` to detect the first run:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if (!defaults.boolForKey("migrated")) {
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "migrated")
    // ... anything else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array within your view controller.

```
var dates = [NSDate]()
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if let retrieved = userDefault.objectForKey("day") {
    dates = retrieved as! [NSDate]
}
```

Then reload your collection view